# Create new dataframe with indexed rows which are duplicate in second df, and drop those rows from original df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

df1

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | zz | zz | value_1 | value_1 |
| 2 | xx | xx | value_1 | value_1 |
| 3 | cc | cc | value_1 | value_1 |

df2

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | zz | zz | value_2 | value_2 |
| 2 | xx | xx | value_2 | value_2 |
| 3 | cc | cc | value_2 | value_2 |
| 3 | cc | cc | value_2 | value_2 |

I would like to create a new dataframe which contains only the rows where the index of ID, A, B are duplicated in df2:

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | cc | cc | value_1 | value_1 |
| 3 | cc | cc | value_2 | value_2 |
| 3 | cc | cc | value_2 | value_2 |

And remove these rows from the original dfs, leaving me with:

df1_new

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | zz | zz | value_1 | value_1 |
| 2 | xx | xx | value_1 | value_1 |

df2_new

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | zz | zz | value_2 | value_2 |
| 2 | xx | xx | value_2 | value_2 |

Comment: You have provided no code attempt. I suggest you look at the pandas .duplicated() method.

Comment: Yes, the ID=3 should be counted 3 times, 2 times with value_2 and 1 time with value_1. 

RE the code attempt sharing, I guarantee that it isn't worth sharing because I concatenated the dfs and then performed a series of arithmetic calculations on the counts of the unique indexes, which is really involved and thanks to Jui Sen's answer completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Original dataframe:

```
df1 = {'ID':[1,2,3],'A':['ZZ','XX','CC'],'B':['ZZ','XX','CC'],'C':['value_1','value_1','value_1'],'D':['value_1','value_1','value_1']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)


df2 = {'ID':[1,2,3,3],'A':['ZZ','XX','CC','CC'],'B':['ZZ','XX','CC','CC'],'C':['value_2','value_2','value_2','value_2'],'D':['value_2','value_2','value_2','value_2']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

[image]
[image]

Step 1:  keep the duplicated column from data 2

```
df3 =df2[df2.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

which gives df3 :
[image]

Step 2: New data frame 1:

```
new_df1 = df1[~df1.ID.isin(df3.ID)]
```

[image]

step:3 New_dataframe 2

```
new_df2 = df2[df2.ID.isin(new_df1.ID)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is really close to what I'm needing - I'll find a way to append the df3 with the ID=3 row from df1. Thank you, this is much more simple than what I have currently! I have a very complicated and not-flexible way of finding duplicates across dfs by concatenating the dfs and then performing some arithmetic calculations on the counts of individual indexes... sigh. Thank you!